# Efficient way to get related Measure Groups given a Dimension in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ssas, data-warehouse

I'm using VB.NET to connect to and parse data from an Analysis Services database.

The problem I'm having is while trying to find all Measure Groups that are related to a given Dimension. I've been digging through the API and it doesn't seem that Dimensions have any information on Measure Groups at all, but Measure Groups can contain Dimensions.

This makes it easy if I want to get a list of related Dimensions given a Measure Group (`measureGroup.Dimensions`), but what I'm looking for is the opposite.

The only thing I can think of is to loop through all the Measure Groups within the Cube and check if it contains a reference to the Dimension in question:

```
Dim dimID As String = "SOME_DIM_ID"
Dim relatedMeasureGroups As New List(Of Amo.MeasureGroup)
For Each mg As Amo.MeasureGroup In _cube.MeasureGroups
    If mg.Dimensions.Contains(dimID) Then
        relatedMeasureGroups.Add(mg)
        Continue For
    End If
Next
```

This works, but is obviously very slow and inefficient. Is there a more direct way that I am just not seeing?

---

EDIT: I should say, I need to do this because I am trying to find all potential [many-to-many Measure Groups for a Dimension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). As you can tell, the way I'm doing it is a bit manual (find Measure Groups related to the initial Dimension, find all Dimensions related to them, and yet again find all Measure Groups related to *those*), so if there is a more direct way to solve that problem, it could bypass my need to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query the SSAS DMV... $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS

```
SELECT  *
FROM    $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS
WHERE   MEASUREGROUP_CARDINALITY = 'MANY' AND
        DIMENSION_CARDINALITY = 'MANY' AND
        [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] = '[Business Unit]'
```

Also, this may come in handy --> http://www.ssas-info.com/VidasMatelisBlog/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/mdschema.jpg

Here's the XMLA-version...

```
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
    <RequestType>MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS</RequestType>
    <Restrictions>
        <RestrictionList xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
            <DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME>[<<insert dimension>>]</DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME>
        </RestrictionList>
    </Restrictions>
    <Properties/>
</Discover>
```

Comment: This looked promising, but after more digging, I cannot make the assumption that the client will have ["system administrator permissions on the Analysis Services instance."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820.aspx#bkmk_tools)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I believe this is the right path, but I'm still having a bit of difficulty. If it wasn't already obvious, I'm pretty green when it comes to SSAS stuff. :P

The XMLA approach is partially working, but every query to any MDSCHEMA type doesn't seem to return any actual rows. Instead I just get the xsd definitions.

For example, querying MDSCHEMA_CUBES returns [this](http://pastebin.com/jGfbTVa5), which doesn't actually tell me about any of the Cubes on the server. Am I missing something else?

Comment: And just for clarity, I am providing a catalog name in my query since I've seen some posts about that potentially being a problem. The Catalog shows up fine when I query DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS, but then no MDSCHEMA queries on that catalog seem to return anything. I have the same problem when trying a MDX query in SQL Server Management Studio (0 rows returned).

Comment: Ah, it appears I just needed to process my Cube in BI. Thanks again!